# ClojureScript Exponent - Get Data From an API

Tags: clojurescript, expo

What is the best way of getting information from an API?

In ClojureScript you can use Ajax GET requests to connect to an API.

For my exponent app, I want to have a button that when pressed, it connects to a website, say Google (doesn't have to be, just an example), and then simply returns the data.

I also need authentication for these requests so how would I add that as well?

In react native you can use `fetch`, how would I use this in ClojureScript?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's really super simple.

`(js/fetch your-arguments)`

Just remember that you can get acces to js functions via `js/`. And don't forget to pass js data-structures to function. I'm talking about `clj->js` function.